# Macro variable generating a space while creating a macro variable in Proc SQL

Tags: macros, sas

*I'm creating a macro variable but when use the same macro variable in my Proc Report this macro is generating a space in front of the value*

**Select COUNT(DISTINCT USUBJID) into: N1 from DMDD where ARMN=1;** [image]
How do I rectify it in the same code??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually 'working as designed' for PROC SQL SELECT INTO.  While all of the other answers are, in some ways, correct, this is a special case as opposed to normal macro variables, such as

```
%let var=          5       ;
%put [&var];
```

where that will return just

> [5]

while this is not doing that.  That is a behavior of `PROC SQL SELECT INTO`, and is intentional.

These two statements:

```
proc sql;
 select name into :name from sashelp.class where name='Alfred';
 select name into :shortname separated by ' ' from sashelp.class where name='Alfred';
quit;
%put `&name` `&shortname`;
```

are non-identical.  `separated by ' '` (or any other separated by) will always trim automatically unless `notrim` is included, and if you have 9.3 or newer, you have a new option, `trimmed`, which you can use if you intend to select a single variable.  I think this behavior was introduced in 9.2 (the non-trimming of select into without a separated by, by default).

If you are only selecting a single value, adding `separated by ' '` will have no impact on your result other than to cause the trimming to occur.

Comment: +1 for not only offering a fix that works, but also explaining the subtleties and even SAS version issues

Answer (score 5):

This is because any macro variable is stored as a character.  If the source data is numeric then SAS uses the best12. format to convert to character, therefore the result is padded with leading blanks.  I get around this by using the CATS function which strips out leading and trailing blanks.  You can't use the LEFT or STRIP functions as these only work against character variables.

```
Select cats(COUNT(DISTINCT USUBJID)) into: N1 from DMDD where ARMN=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%cmpres()` macro to remove blanks.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/64754/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0tvdbcgr9xc6dn14wmx9hpd6h51.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Select trim(put(COUNT(DISTINCT USUBJID), 16. -L)) into: N1 from DMDD where ARMN=1;
```

Use PUT() to format the output string with -L (left) alignement.

Comment: This line of code gives a trailling blanks after the value. But, thank you.